# error on line 75 at column 16: AttValue: " or ' expected

Tags: html, css, svg

I'm getting an error on this first line:

```
    <a xlink:href=“#dccomics” xlink:title=“DC Comics”>
    <rect x="1023.509" y="-612.968" fill="none" stroke="#000000" stroke-width="0.5" stroke-miterlimit="10" width="203.092" height="72.888"/>
```

Can anyone spot it?

Answer (score 5):

yes, you're using the wrong kind of quotes “ and ” are invalid and subtly different from ".

The rect has them correct.

Have you been using a word processing program to edit the file? Best not to if you have as they do tend to stick these kind of quotes in.

Comment: Ahhh! Yes, in TextEdit.
Rookie mistake.